# Is there any way to open CKEditor dialog manually?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular8, ckeditor4.x, fckeditor

In my case I need to open **Link properties** dialog via one click on the a tag.

[Link Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6REF.png)

Is there any solution for this? Is it possible or not?

I'm using CKEditor4 version and Angular 8 version.

I tried to catch one click event on the `<a>` tag and trigger dblclick. Double click event works but Link Properties still didn't open.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', (evt: any) => {
  evt.editor.editable().on('click', (event: any) => {
    $(event.data.$.target).dblclick();
  });
});
```

So for now I catch one click event on each `<a>` tag but still can't open Link Properties dialog for current element. I need to know is it possible to open this dialog manually and will be great to understand how.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too vague. Try adding some code to the post so it gives us some context to what you are asking and enable us to help you better.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer, I updated my topic, could you please check is it make sense?